# react: Create and use dynamic variables

Tags: reactjs, variables, redux, babeljs

I've a list/array `cities = ["Bangalore", "Delhi", "Hyderabad", "Mumbai", "Chennai"]`. I need dynamic variables like `[city]Weather`, `[city]Temperature`, etc. Ex: I need BangaloreWeather, DelhiWeather, HyderabadWeather, MumbaiWeather, ChennaiWeather and similarly for temperature too.

I tried using 
1) `${city}Weather`, but got an error as "Complex binding patterns require an initialization value",
2) `city+"Weather"`
    Please help me in solving the issue.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ES6, this may help ?

```
const outcome =  ["Bangalore", "Delhi", "Hyderabad", "Mumbai", "Chennai"].reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
  accumulator[currentValue+"Weather"] = Math.random();
  return accumulator;
},{});

OUTPUT: 
{
  "BangaloreWeather": 0.7831037919683015,
  "DelhiWeather": 0.03695139822965743,
  "HyderabadWeather": 0.10986926586742629,
  "MumbaiWeather": 0.676334213130112,
  "ChennaiWeather": 0.9095092973413457
}
```